# FastReport imprime espaço em branco. (Delphi 2010)

Tags: delphi, fast-reports

Sou iniciante com fastreport 5, estou com um problema, se alguém puder dar uma dica.

Estou fazendo um relatório que possui vários DataBand, é tipo uma escada de dados, cada band filho de um band.

O problema é que esta aparecendo um espaço enorme entre os databand. Ex: Se acaba o databand no meio da folha ele começa o outro databand na outra folha.

Teria como eu tirar esse espaço? Acabar um data band e começar outro.

Outro ponto que fast imprime a band inteira em outra pagina, e não quebra a band. Ex: Não Começa no fim da pagina um e termina na pagina 2, já imprime direto a outra band inteira na próxima pagina.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Provavelmente a propriedade **KeepTogether** das bandas devem estar **true**, mude para **false** e veja se resolve o seu problema.